# Why is Y, a constrained const generic, reported as unconstrained here?

Tags: generics, rust, const-generics

I’m writing a fixed-size bit sequence type in Rust with the nightly features `generic_const_exprs` and `int_roundings`, and I’m able to `impl` `BitAndAssign` as such (I’ve not included the body because it isn’t necessary to verify that the first example builds and the second one doesn’t):

```rust
trait Bits {
    const BITS: u32;
}
impl Bits for u32 {
    const BITS: u32 = Self::BITS;
}

const fn bslen(x: u32, b: u32) -> usize {
    x.div_ceil(b) as usize
}

struct BitSet<const X: u32, T: Bits = u32>
where
    [(); bslen(X, T::BITS)]:
{
    data: [T; bslen(X, T::BITS)]
}

use std::ops::BitAndAssign;

impl<const X: u32, const Y: u32, T: Bits>
    BitAndAssign<&BitSet<Y, T>>
for BitSet<X, T>
where
    [(); bslen(X, T::BITS)]:,
    [(); bslen(Y, T::BITS)]:
{
    fn bitand_assign(&mut self, other: &BitSet<Y, T>) {}
}
```

But when I try to change it to use `Borrow<BitSet<Y, T>>` instead of `&BitSet<Y, T>`, like so:

```rust
use std::ops::BitAndAssign;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

impl<const X: u32, const Y: u32, T: Bits, BSY: Borrow<BitSet<Y, T>>>
    BitAndAssign<BSY>
for BitSet<X, T>
where
    [(); bslen(X, T::BITS)]:,
    [(); bslen(Y, T::BITS)]:
{
    fn bitand_assign(&mut self, other: BSY) {}
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0207]: the const parameter `Y` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/minrep.rs:22:26
   |
22 | impl<const X: u32, const Y: u32, T: Bits, BSY: Borrow<BitSet<Y, T>>>
   |                          ^ unconstrained const parameter
   |
```

I’m not sure what this means, since `Y` is constrained, or why it only happens in the second case. `generic_const_exprs` is unstable, so this could just be a compiler bug, but I figured I should ask just in case there’s something obvious, or not so obvious, that I’m missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `BSY` type could implement `Borrow<BitSet<Y, T>>` for *multiple* `Y`s. In this case, knowing that `BitSet<X, T>` implements `BitAndAssign<BSY>` is simply not enough for the compiler to infer the value of `Y` as there are multiple options.

This is why the compiler complains that `Y` is unconstrained -- given the type `BitSet<X, T>` and its implementation of the `BitAndAssign<BSY>` trait (for a particular type `BSY`), the compiler cannot necessarily determine the value of `Y`. On the other hand, given the type `BitSet<X, T>` and its implementation of the `BitAndAssign<&BitSet<Y, T>>` trait, the compiler knows exactly what value of `Y` to use as it is present in the trait definition.

Comment: Wouldn’t `impl<const X: u32, T: Bits, BSX: Borrow<BitSet<X, T>>> BitAndAssign<BSX>` have the same problem?

Comment: @hornblende No, `X` and `T` are directly part of the type the trait is implemented for, `BitSet<X, T>`, and `BSX` is part of the trait being implemented, `BitAndAssign<BSX>`. To put it another way, this trait is used in the `bitset &= bsx;` syntax, where the types of both `bitset` and and `bsx` would be fully known.